# Trying To Make A Listbox Horizontal Inside a Grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a grid of size 400 x 150 in which I would like to add a Listbox.

The Listbox is composed of a grid that contains a TextBlock.

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="150">
    <ListBox x:Name="list" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid Width = "80">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right"   />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  Text="{Binding  name}" />
                     </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

But the list is displayed vertically.

I tried to use a VirtualizingStackPanel but the problem is  that the borders of the grids don't appear correctly.

How can I make this list look horizontal, with the borders of the grid that contains the textblock visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use like this to have horizontal scrollViewer of Listbox

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="150">
<ListBox x:Name="list" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid Width = "80">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right"   />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  Text="{Binding  name}" />
                 </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
 </Grid>
```

In addition to this You have to adjust height and width of both listbox and grid according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, you don't want a `StackPanel` *inside* the `DataTemplate`, you actually want a horizontally laid out items inside the `ListBox`. You need to change the `ListBox.ItemsPanel` and you need to disable vertical scroll and enable horizontal scroll in the `ListBox`. Here is the full XAML:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    CanVerticallyScroll="False"
                                    CanHorizontallyScroll="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ItemsPanel to change the oriention of listBox. and the borderThickness is also necessary.Hope I can help you. Thx!

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="150">
    <ListBox x:Name="list" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid Width = "80">
      <!-- if you want to use border to separate items, HorizontalAlignment="Right";
           and if use it as container, HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" -->
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  Text="{Binding  name}" />
                     </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Chris is on the right lines,  but I am sure you need a content  presenter in the ItemsPanel template.

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="150">
<ListBox x:Name="list" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid Width = "80">
  <!-- if you want to use border to separate items, HorizontalAlignment="Right";
       and if use it as container, HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" -->
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  Text="{Binding  name}" />
        </Border>   
                 </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it could help you:

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="150">
        <ListBox x:Name="list" >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>              
                        <Grid Width = "80">
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right"   />
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  Text="{Binding  name}" />
                         </Grid>                
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: use this one it would help

Answer (score 0):

Use ItemsPanel property of listbox. try this its work for me.

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="150">
    <ListBox x:Name="list" >
      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid Width = "80">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right"   />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  Text="{Binding  name}" />
                     </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```